# Debug-only methods or interface in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie to Android and Java--lots of experience with C/C++/C#.

I have in interface that looks like this:

```
class WellNamedClass {
    void greatMethodToCallWhenever() { /*...*/ }

    void debugOnlyMethod() { /*...*/ }
}
```

In the the languages mentioned above, I would either #ifdef the entire debugOnlyMethod method out or #ifdef the implementation out so it simply does nothing, but Java doesn't have a preprocessor.

I'm totally comfortable with having the code there and checking at run-time whether we are in a debug build, but I can't even find a way of doing that.

I've found suggestions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041/how-to-remove-debug-statements-from-production-code-in-java) where you create a class with a constant indicating whether debug (or whatever else you want) is enabled. This could work, but then you have to manually change code to get a debug vs. a release build.

Has anyone else solved this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method we're going to use is have a JNI call into our native component that will tell us whether we are running in debug mode. We have to have the native component anyway, and will make a few JNI calls at startup so it's a relatively simple solution, since C++ has a preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need this, BTW you can put a static global variable, like this:

```
class WellNamedClass{

public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
...
}
```

And check your debug method with an if statement, like:

```
if(WellNamedClass.DEBUG){
    debugOnlyMethod();
}
```

Starting with java you could play with this.

When you get more experience, you could try annotations, aop, or any other advanced programming technique.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'd prefer to build able to build a release build and a debug build without changing code.

Comment: @richarbernal, none of those "advanced" programming techniques address the OP's fundamental question of how to have a different value based on the build (debug/release/etc.).

Comment: Then you must put a configuration file with the debug mode option in instance of the constant or read a program parameter

Answer (score 0):

> This could work, but then you have to manually change code to get a
>   debug vs. a release build.

One popular approach is to pass system property using `-D` flag to the VM. You can then either use `System.getProperty` directly or initialize a `static field` from that property.

`System.getenv` will also work.

Comment: I have only just recently started with Android, but from the output of `adb shell dalvikvm -help ` it seems to be possible.

Comment: For Android use if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){}  Gradle builds this variable for us.

Answer (score 0):

Long overdue but it might help anyone else who ends up here in the future.

Simple answer; **do not** use conditional logic to determine what state the build is in. [Configure a build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) and use the appropriate source sets for your configured build. It seems like more work up front but ultimately will save you a ton of time and trouble in the long run.